# Does a matrix representation of an operator must be square?

Tags: matrices

Does a matrix representation of an operator must be square? Or could be $n\times m$ where $n\neq m$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "operator"?  That term is sometimes used in different ways.

Comment: If by *operator* you mean what's meant almost always, i.e. a linear map between a vector space **and itself** (i.e., an endomorphism), then the answer is yes...when the dimension is finite, of course, otherwise we'd be talking of infinite matrices.

Comment: If you're asking in the context of operator theory, the answer is no. Howevr, if you mean that the domain and codomain are the same, then the answer is yes and I think you should remove the tag "operator-theory"

Comment: Indeed I was talking about a finite dimension. And yes between a vector space and it self.
Tag for  "operator theory" removed.

Answer (score 1):

A linear operator from $m$-dimensional vector space into $n$-dimensional vector space can be represented by a matrix of size $n\times m$, that is $n$ rows and $m$ columns.

When $n=m$  (in particular, if the domain and codomain are the same space) this is a square matrix.